# Google Colab Jave Script Display Output issue only on Mac?

Tags: google-colaboratory, macbookpro

The following error is what I get when trying to work inside my Colab notebook on my MacBook:

Could not load the JavaScript files needed to display output. This is probably because your Google Account login access has expired or because third-party cookies are not allowed by your browser. Please reload this page.

On my windows computer, the error never occurs. I have tried disabling extensions + clearing cookies + incognito window, does anyone know how to fix this? I am often spending most of my time on campus so I have limited access to my desktop rig during the day and would love the option to code while I am out.